# Запитання і питання. Яка між ними різниця?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, значення-слів, пароніми

Як у розмовній мові, так і на письмі зустрічаються обидва слова: "запитання" та "питання". Хотілось би розуміти, коли яке слово правильно вживати.

[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapytannja)  містить визначення даного поняття:

> ЗАПИТА́ННЯ, я, сер.
>
> - Звертання до кого-небудь з метою з'ясування чогось; питання.
> - Те, що вимагає з'ясування.
> - Тема для відповіді при перевірці знань учня, при    збиранні якихось відомостей і т. ін.
>
> ПИТА́ННЯ, я, сер.
>
> Звертання до кого-небудь, яке потребує відповіді, роз'яснення і т. ін.

*Тлумачення практично тотожні, то як зрозуміти різницю між «**запитанням**» і «**питанням**»?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайті [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/zapitannya-y-pitannya) пише, що:

> Деякі мовознавці радять розрізняти ці два слова:
>
> **Запитання** – звернення до когось, яке потребує відповіді, вимога, прохання з приводу чогось; запит.
>
> **Питання** – справа, проблема, що потребує розв’язання, обговорення чи дослідження. Знак питання.
> [image]

О. Авраменко каже у [Сніданку з 1+1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1h11MD2tCY) так:

> "**Запитання**" і "**питання**" є ***синонімами*** у значенні звертання до когось, яке потребує відповіді. Тому правильно сказати: і *поставити питання*, і *поставвити запитання*.
>
> А ось у значенні "проблема або справа, яку треба вирішити", то тут треба вживати тільки слово **питання**.